# Ubuntu App VM in Qubes

Tags: debian

How to install or set up a Ubuntu VM (Template or APP) in Qubes OS?

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to reference the [Official Qubes OS Documentation](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/) for any information you need. They have a handy guide located [here](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/building-archlinux-template/) on how to create a template VM. The process is very straight forward, however it refers to Arch Linux but you can substitute the changes near the end to Ubuntu or pretty much any other operating system instead of Arch. That guide works to create a VM template the "Qubes Way" and I highly recommend you read it over and follow every step.

If you are new to Linux operating systems I suggest you simply run Ubuntu on your computer as opposed to using Qubes OS but the [documentation](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/) should answer most of your question and the [Archlinux template building instructions](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/building-archlinux-template/) is very comprehensive and will show you step by step what you need to do to have an Ubuntu VM Template for your Qubes install. Best of Luck!